# How should Gauss's law deal with surface charges?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

If a charge is kept on the surface of a body then do we consider it enclosed and account it in Gauss's theorem?  Take for example a charge $q$ kept on top of a hemispherical shell.  Finding the flux through the curved surface, would it be same as passing through the circular cross-section or should we consider some charge enclosed?

As another example, suppose 12 infinite wires with uniform linear charge density $\lambda$ lie along the 12 edges of a cube in which each edge has length $L$.  What is the electric flux through any face of the cube?  By symmetry all faces will have equal flux, so we can just use Gauss's law where the surface is just the combination of those 6 faces, and the total charge enclosed is $\lambda L$ for each of the 12 wires, so
\begin{equation}
 6 \times (\text{flux of one face}) = \frac{12 \lambda L} {\epsilon_0},
\end{equation}
which means
\begin{equation}
 \text{flux of one face} = \frac{2 \lambda L} {\epsilon_0}.
\end{equation}
But my answer does not agree with the answer given in the book, which is $\frac{\lambda L}{2\epsilon_0}$.  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Please read the answers to [this question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) for how to ask homework-like questions like this.  We need to some details about what you tried.  It would also be helpful if you could mention what you mean by "my answer is not matching" — what is your answer and what isn't it matching?

Comment: @Mike i made the necessary corrections

Comment: If a charge is kept on the surface of a body then do we consider it enclosed and account it in gauss theorm? 
Take for example a charge q is kept on top of a hemispherical shell. Find the flux through curved surface? 
Now in this would it be same as passing through the circular crosssection or we will consider some charge enclosed which would change the answer. 
A proper explanation is appreciable

Comment: My account has been blocked so i m posting my question here

Comment: I don't think you're blocked; it's just that your two questions (*especially* the first one) didn't ask about specific physics concepts or show any effort to work through the problem.  But you should still be able to edit the questions, and if you do ask about specifics or show effort, your questions may be reopened.  Really read that beige box above, and follow its advice.  In particular, the questions you asked in that comment are very good (though the last sentence isn't entirely clear).  To get you started, I'll edit the question to add those in and improve what you had.

Comment: A Gaussian surface shall not pass over charges. Plus, we consider point charges, so it's not half-inside or anything, it's just belonging to the surface or not, and you better not take the surface containing charges.

Comment: I would answer this properly if I could, but since it's still closed, I'll just try to be brief here.  There are three ways to get this answer.  First, note that the cube question (as posted) never says that these "wires" should be thought of as lines with no thickness.  Real wires have thickness, and the charge is distributed evenly more-or-less at the surfaces of those wires.  So if the center of a wire goes along an edge of this cube, only one quarter of the wire is inside the cube, which means that only one quarter of the *charge* is inside the cube, so you should divide your answer by 4.

Comment: Second, it's tricky to use Gauss's Law when charges are *in* the surface. Usually, what you want to do is change the charge distribution so that it will give basically the same field, but doesn't quite go through the surface, and then take the limit as that distribution approaches your original one.  In this case, even if you wanted true line charges with no thickness, you could idealize them as narrow cylinders with tiny strips cut out to let the Gaussian surface pass through, and then take the limit as those strips get smaller and smaller, and then as the cylinders get narrower and narrower.

Comment: So that situation is basically the same as the wires with finite thickness, and again, you would need to divide your answer by 4 since only 1/4 of the cylinder is *inside* the cube.

Comment: Finally, it's not hard to directly calculate the flux.  Since any face passes *through* four of the wires, the perpendicular component of $\mathbf{E}$ from any of those four will be zero.  Similarly, each of the four wires perpendicular to the face create an electric field that is perpendicular to that face, and so contribute nothing to the flux.  So all you need to calculate is the flux from the four wires "across from" that face.  By symmetry, the contribution to the flux from each of those wires is the same.  And...

Comment: ...you should be able to convince yourself that the flux from any one of those wires is $$\text{flux from each of the 4 wires} = \int_0^L \frac{\lambda L^2}{2 \pi \epsilon_0 (L^2 + x^2)}\, dx = \frac{\lambda L}{8 \epsilon_0}.$$  Multiply that by the 4 wires that contribute to the flux, and you get the same answer again.  So in all three ways, you get the same answer as the book: $$\text{flux through any face of the cube} = \frac{\lambda L}{2 \epsilon_0}.$$

Answer (score -1):

I like this problem! Consider the flux experienced by one face.  One can draw E field diagrams to be convinced that the flux it experiences is caused by two segments across from it.  Next, solve for the flux caused by *one* segment.  I argue in the drawing [image: See drawing] that the total flux thru a new cube surrounding the wire = q enclosed/epsilon0 = 16*Flux thru one side.  This shape works because all sides of it experience the same flux.  16 because you'd need 16 faces of the cube to surround the wire.  I drew 8 of them in profile, but the rest would be non-profile, if that makes sense.

You can double the flux from one wire, on one face, to get the flux by two wires on one face.  And multiple that by 6 to get the total flux experienced by the entire cube.